# Lua table lookup

Tags: lua, find

I know this seems like a dumb question but how do I search a lua table for a given item? let's say I have a table like this:

```
local table = {
    itemA = 0.8,
    itemB = 1.2,
    itemC = 1
}
```

Is there, say, a function named `table.find` or something? It's also late here so I'm not thinking too clearly at the moment...

Comment: I fixed the syntax error in your sample...  The only dumb  question is the one you don't ask. Especially when learning a new language.

Comment: Not exactly learning it but i am trying to get back into it lately, i use it on and off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can lookup items in the table either using the `[]` operator:

```
x=table["itemA"]
```

or by using the `.` operator:

```
x=table.itemA
```

**Edited** because original code is now syntax-correct.

Comment: +1.  Note that the dot only works if the key happens to be a string value made up of legal identifier characters. Tables can be indexed by values of any type (except nil) most of which will require the `[]` notation.

Comment: Just checking, in your example x will be nil if the value does not exist in the table?